# tee and assigning to variable?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, tee

I need to see output on the screen and at the same time grep the output and send grep result to variable. I think it can be done with tee but I can't figure out how exactly. I tried

```
mycommand | tee myvar=$(grep -c keyword)
mycommand | tee  >(myvar=$(grep -c keyword))
```

but this does not work. How should it be, preferrably without writting to files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You would do this:

```sh
myvar=$( mycommand | tee /dev/tty | grep -c keyword )
```

Use tee to pipe the output directly to your terminal, while using stdout to parse the output and save that in a variable.

Comment: Note: this works in `bash` but not `zsh`. Gordon Davisson's answer works for both.

Comment: @DeusXMachina It works in zsh for me.  Can you offer a failing example?

Comment: @wim Hm. Just tried it and it worked this time (zsh on mac and in a linux container). That was several months ago, no idea what I ran. Shrug.

Comment: It won't work when a TTY is not available, e.g. systemd service. [This other solution](https://serverfault.com/a/989827/954276) works even under that circumstance.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with some file descriptor juggling:

```
{ myvar=$(mycommand | tee /dev/fd/3 | grep keyword); } 3>&1
```

Explanation: file descriptor #0 is used for standard input, #1 for standard output, and #2 for standard error; #3 is usually unused. In this command, the `3>&1` copies FD #1 (standard output) onto #3, meaning that within the `{ }`, there are two ways to send output to the terminal (or wherever standard output is going).

The `$( )` captures only FD #1, so anything sent to #3 from inside it will bypass it. Which is exactly what `tee /dev/fd/3` does with its input (as well as copying it to its standard output, which is the `grep` command's standard input).

Essentially, FD #3 is being used to smuggle output past the `$( )` capture.

Comment: The status `$?` of this will be that of `grep`, right?

Comment: @mpen Correct; grep is the "last" command in the process substitution (the `$()` bit), so its status is reflected in the exit status of the subshell running that; that subshell is the only real command here, so its status winds up in `$?`. But note that if you did something like `{ local myvar=...` or `{ export myvar=...`, then `$?` would be the status of the `local` or `export` or whatever command instead.

Comment: +1 as it even works with systemd services.

Comment: When I use this in a CI pipeline, I get the error `tee: /dev/fd/3: No such device or address`. What should I do? The same happens with the `/dev/tty` solution, although I see both devices when I do a `ls -lLR /dev/`.

Comment: @Joerg There's probably something different about the environment the CI pipeline runs in, but I have no idea what that difference is. Maybe try replacing the `tee /dev/fd/3` with `tee >(cat >&3)` (note: this must run under bash, so make sure your CI pipeline uses bash, not just sh).

Comment: I see output using `/dev/tty` but using `/dev/fd3` and `3>&1` produces nothing.

Comment: I'm getting `tee: /dev/fd/3: Permission denied` when using this in my script. It works fine when I write a simple script and run it like that from an interactive shell, though. Maybe fd/3 is a bad choice in more complex scripts? It does some magic with setpriv to run itself as an unprivileged user (among other tricks), so is it possible that this means that fd/3 is already being used for somethings else, and is there a good way to work around this?

Comment: @SteenSchütt I don't know why that'd happen, maybe something to do with how your OS manages permissions fo /dev/fd and whatever you're doing with setpriv. Does replacing `tee /dev/fd/3` with `tee >(cat >&3)` work? If not, I'd recommend trying to isolate the problem -- test your script while simplifying it as much as possible, so you wind up with just the bare minimum necessary to trigger the problem. That'd give a much better idea what's causing it, and thus how to fix/work around it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `tee >(cat - >&3)` works. I also tried opening the fd from the parent shell with `exec 3>&1`, but it didn't appear to make any difference. At least it works, but the process substitution is a bit obtuse. Do you know why this construct works when the other doesn't? Because I'm not really sure why it makes a difference. Simplifying the script is a ton of work. It's definitely a project that shouldn't have been done in bash, yet here I am :')

Comment: @SteenSchütt The problem has to be something to do with how /dev/fd works on your OS and how that interacts with whatever else your script is doing; without being able to reproduce it and run experiments, I have no idea beyond that.

Answer (score -2):

You can use like below. If you want to append use `-a` option with tee remember it will create a file with your variable name.

```
$ ls | tee $(echo asktyagi)
asktyagi1

$ ls -lthr
total 12K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 asktyagi asktyagi    8 Oct 29 08:54 asktyagi1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 asktyagi asktyagi   23 Oct 29 08:54 asktyagi
```

Comment: Just FYI, tee will accept file name not the actual variable. if question if about that you need to find another way.

Comment: Perhaps there's misunderstanding. I don't need to write to file but to variable. And not to file which name is in variable. And I know tee can accept command/pipe instead of file name to send the output too.

Comment: You should not use tee in that case `The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.` can't pass variable it should be a file.